# How to solve cast issues in ValidationRule classes' properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, webtest

I need to create a few tests for the user roles in a web application. To minimize the description, one of the tests involves checking if a menu entry is displayed or not for an user.

For this test, I use a table called UserRoles, that looks like this:

```
sUserName    bDoesntHaveMenuX
User1        1
User2        0
User3        1
```

bDoesntHaveMenuX is of type bit.

I have a class derived from ValidationRule that checks if a certain text is present in a page, based on a XPath expression to locate the node where to look for the text.
The public properties of this class are:

```
string XPathExpression
string Text
bool FailIfFound
```

The last one dictates if the rule should fail if the text is found or not found.

In the test I added a datasource for the table mentioned in the beginning, called DS. 
For the request I'm interested in I added a new instance of my validation rule class, with the following values:

```
Text=MenuX
XPathExpression=//div[@id='menu']//td
FailIfFound={{DS.UserRoles.bDoesntHaveMenuX}}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.
The reason seems to be that the data binding process creates a context variable
DS.UserRoles.bDoesntHaveMenuX has the value "False" or "True". The value is a string, so the binding results in a casting error.

My options, as far as I can think of, are:

1. Change the validation rule to accept strings for FailIfFound. Not a valid
   option, for 2 reasons: it's a hack and the same rule is used in
   other places.
2. Make a new validation rule that will use the above mentioned one,
   and implement the FailIfFound as string. I also don't like this, for
   the same reason as above. It's a hack.
3. Make the test coded and do the proper cast before passing the data
   to the validation rule. I don't like this one because I prefer to
   have the test as coded only if there is no other way.

Which brings me to the question. Is there another way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the fundamental issue is that you have no control over how the data-binding treats the 'bit' data type, and it's getting converted to string instead of bool.

The only solution I can think of (which is sadly still a bit of a hack, but not so egregious as changing FailIfFound to string) is to create a WebTestPlugin, and in the PreRequestDataBinding or PreRequest event, convert the value from string to bool.  Don't forget to add the plugin to your test(s) (easy mistake I have made).

Then when the validation rule is created it should pick up the nice new bool value and work correctly.

e.g.

```
  string val = e.WebTest.Context["DS.UserRoles.bDoesntHaveMenuX"].ToString();
  e.WebTest.Context["DS.UserRoles.bDoesntHaveMenuX"] = (val == "True");
```

I didn't actually try this... hope it works.

**EDIT:  round two... a better solution**

1. Change the FailIfFound property to string (in a subclass as you mentioned), so it can work properly with data-binding.
2. Implement a TypeConverter that provides a dropdown list of valid values for the property in the rule's PropertyGrid (True, False), so in the GUI it looks identical to the rule having FailIfFound as a bool.  You can still type your own value into the box when necessary (e.g. for data-binding).
3. Add the path of the .dll containing the TypeConverter code to your test project's References section.

This is what I have started doing and it is much more satisfying than having to type 'True' or 'False' in the property's edit box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using a WebTestPlugin is a nice idea, somehow it slipped my mind. :)

But there are 2 downsides to this approach:

1) There doesn't seem to be a way (or I couldn't find it) to use databinding for a bool property of a ValidationRule. The VisualStudio properties panel imposes a dropdown with True/False. So it seems that I have to use the coded webtest for this, which is something I wanted to avoid.

2) The code above has to be maintained for all the boolean columns in the data source. This might be somehow solved with reflection, but it starts getting very complicated. :-/

Comment: Great points... you're right, you can't databind on properties except for String types. For this reason, even though it is ugly and requires more coding, I use String for most of my properties in my custom rules & plugins.  Regarding (2), you could simply add a property to your WebTestPlugin that takes the data source prefix (e.g. "DS.UserRoles") and then specifically looks only for properties that start with that string and have 'True' or 'False' values, then convert the values to bool as above.  In this way it will work for all columns without any extra effort.

Comment: That should have said "looks only for 'context parameters' that start with that string".

Comment: Despite the fact that I'm not able to reproduce the scenario I described in the question (I cannot set the boolean FailIfFound property to anything else than False/True), I think your answer is quite pertinent in this context so I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks.